# show double quotes inside(JSON) jquery datatables

Tags: php, json, parsing, datatable

I am using jquery data tables server side method

example here
http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/server_side.html

My `JSON RESPONSE`( example)

```
 {"sEcho": 0, "iTotalRecords": 8, "iTotalDisplayRecords": 8, "aaData":
  [ ["1","3D Panasonic VIERA 50' LED Television","Electronics" ],
["2","Wireless Telephone Set - 3 in 1","Electronics" ]] }
```

you can note `3D Panasonic VIERA 50' LED Television` single  quote in that string 
this works fine. but using `3D Panasonic VIERA 50" LED Television` double quote that makes `JSON PARSE ERROR`

how can i escape that double quote inside json
and how can i display exactly `3D Panasonic VIERA 50" LED Television` like this in grid

Comment: u must read [JSON Parser](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow very simple i found myself

```
function getJsondata($str){
return htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($str));
}
```

this function strips the  `\` and   it also displays the `"` on the grid without parse error

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JSON standard specifies `\"` as an escape sequence for a double quote within a string.

Comment: is escapse fine but it adds that slash on display also ... i don't won't display that slash

Comment: Well, maybe this datatables component doesn't handle JSON correctly. If you don't do any processing of incoming data in your JavaScript and their server method doesn't unescape JSON strings for you I see no way of transmitting double quotes using this method. You have to escape it when sending JSON because otherwise it is not a valid JSON. And of course you have to unescape it before displaying.